# Powershell doesn't return key value in hashtable

Tags: powershell, null, hashtable

```
PS C:\Users\kris> $hashx=@{}
PS C:\Users\kris> $(Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | Select-Object ProcessId, Name) | ForEach-Object { $hashx[$_.ProcessId]=$_.Name }
PS C:\Users\kris> $hashx
    
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    1292                           svchost.exe
    6032                           StartMenuExperienceHost.exe
    428                            smss.exe
    4736                           powershell.exe
    2580                           svchost.exe
    5628                           explorer.exe
    5164                           taskhostw.exe
PS C:\Users\kris> $hashx['5164']
PS C:\Users\kris> $hashx.5164
PS C:\Users\kris> $hashx."5164"
PS C:\Users\kris> $hashx.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

Can anyone explain me what i do wrong? i'm beginner in powershell, and i don't understand why it returns null value by key?

Comment: @AdminOfThings yes, i do so

Comment: It would help if you try to explain what exactly you're trying to retrieve, and why you're using a Hashtable to retrieve it. I know from your post that you appear to be trying to output the Value, _(Name)_, which is assigned to the Name, _(ProcessID)_, but I'm not really understanding how you already know the ProcessID. If you knew it, then you'd just use, `$(Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * From Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = '5164'").Name` to retireve the process Name assigned to that process ID, instead of creating a Hashtable.

Comment: The problem is that your command returns keys of type `[uint32]`. So you need to cast each key to that type--> `$hashx[[uint32]5164]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Get-CimInstance Win32_Process` returns `ProcessId` property as type `System.UInt32`. You will need to cast your key retrieval values to that type or convert the `ProcessId` values to `System.Int32`. The reason is by default the shell interprets unquoted or uncast whole numbers as `System.Int32` provided the number is less than or equal to `[int32]::maxvalue` or `System.Int64` otherwise.

In your case, you can simply use the syntax below if you don't mind working with `Uint32`:

```
$hashx[[uint32]5164]
```

Personally, I would convert the `ProcessId` value to `System.Int32` (using accelerator `[int]`) when adding it to the hash table:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process |
    Select-Object ProcessId, Name | ForEach-Object {
        $hashx[[int]$_.ProcessId] = $_.Name 
    }

# Now the keys can be accessed using Int32 numbers
$hashx[5164]
```

---

As an aside, you can discover property types yourself with the `Get-Member` command:

```
Get-CimInstance win32_Process | 
    Select -First 1 -Property ProcessId | Get-Member


   TypeName: Selected.Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
ProcessId   NoteProperty uint32 ProcessId=0
```

Notice the definition of `ProcessId` shows type `uint32`.